# Best way to Show Complex and Lengthy Table Headings

Tags: web-app, tables, data-tables

So I have been creating a design for a table in which there is

```
Heading Tr1=> Roll | Name | Subjects      | Subjects | Subjects |||| | Aggregate |

Heading Tr2=>             |part|part|total|
```

[image]

Now the problem is that I don't control the part names, it's a user input. If I use the part name directly in the 2nd row then it can result in very wide columns while the data for there columns are usually 2 digit numerical numbers.

Approach I am using is that I am replacing part names by P1,P2,P3 along with info icon which on clicking show a popover containing the name and marks related to a part. As Follow:
[image]

Comment: Is this for a web application?

Comment: Hi @jazZRo Yes It's a web Based Application

Answer (score 2):

Keep aggregate only. Let Users drill down the information on demand for each row by either:

- presenting details in one extra row appearing under row of choice
- presenting details in separate table
- presenting details in tooltip in vertical way for many parts